# Spring-boot not respecting liquibase properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm in the process of setting up liquibase to manage my database in a new spring boot application.  I need the liquibase dependency in my classpath to reset the database state after certain integration tests run.  During my tests I do not want liquibase to be enabled via spring auto config during application context initialization.  I've tried adding liquibase.enabled = false to the application.properties, however when I debug the LiquibaseAutoConfiguration class it appears that enabled is always set to true.

I'm not new to spring, but I am new to spring-boot's auto configuration. Has anyone had issues with spring boot not respecting properties in application.properties?

My setup is fairly minimal:

Relevant code snippets:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBootClass.class })
public class databaseTests{
    @Before
    public void setup() throws LiquibaseException, SQLException {
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(dataSource.getConnection()));
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor("src/main/resources/"),database );
        liquibase.dropAll();
        liquibase.update("test");
    }
..
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ DataSourceConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class, OauthConfig.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties 
public class SpringBootClass {
..
}

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
<!--   <liquibase.version>3.3.5</liquibase.version> -->


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your tests to consume `application.properties` you need to run them as a Spring Boot application. Your use of `@ContextConfiguration` means that you're currently running them as a vanilla Spring Framework application. Replace the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Comment: This is also a good solution, ultimately because I don't need spring boot for these tests i ended up going with the ConfigFileAplicationContextInitializer in my answer above.  Thank you for taking the time to answer, I will accept yours as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Should have RTFM...

from [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility)

> ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer is an
>   ApplicationContextInitializer that can apply to your tests to load
>   Spring Boot application.properties files. You can use this when you
>   don’t need the full features provided by
>   @SpringApplicationConfiguration.
>
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class,
>       initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)

Changing my config to use the initializer worked.